# How can i get one table to show the results from two different CSV files in python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

i have two separate CSV files that I'm running through python and matplot to generate the results with a visual table. Ideally, I would like to then compare the results from the two tables with both results on one table, one line representing each table and their results. I can get each table to be represented with their own script separately, but I'm having some trouble on working out how to combine both together. Below is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score


df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\avalo\Desktop\Data.csv')
print (df)
X = list(df.iloc[:, 0])
Y = list(df.iloc[:, 1])

plt.scatter(X, Y, color='b')
plt.title("Levels of Methane (CH4) Emissions (Tonnes) From The UK 2010 - 2019")
plt.xlabel("Years")
plt.ylabel("Number of Tonnes")

plt.show()

model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X, Y)
model = LinearRegression().fit(X, Y)


print('Data.csv', r_sq)
```

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import linear_model

df = pd.read_csv(r'/home/*my user name*/Downloads/Data2.csv')
print (df)

X = list(df.iloc[:, 0])
Y = list(df.iloc[:, 1])

plt.scatter(X, Y, color='b')
plt.title("Levels of Methane (CH4) Emissions (Tonnes) From Denmark 2010 - 2019")
plt.xlabel("Years")
plt.ylabel("Number of Tonnes")

plt.show()
```

The different directories are because one is from my laptop running Linux and the other is on my main windows machine, just thought I would mention that to avoid any confusion.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import linear_model

df = pd.read_csv(r'/home/*my user name*/Downloads/Data2.csv')
df = pd.read_csv(r'/home/*my user name*/Downloads/Data.csv')
print (df)

X = list(df.iloc[:, 0])
Y = list(df.iloc[:, 1])

plt.scatter(X, Y, color='b')
plt.title("Levels of Methane (CH4) Emissions (Tonnes) From Denmark 2010 - 2019")
plt.xlabel("Years")
plt.ylabel("Number of Tonnes")

plt.show()
```

Am i doing something wrong with importing both CSVs?

Comment: What is the specific problem that occurs when you put them together?

Comment: @fdireito if i add the two import lines together it still prints only the data from the first CSV file mentioned. I cant seem to get both results to print on one single graph to show a comparison. Am I missing something?

Comment: Could you provide the actual code with them together, please?

Comment: It won't let me paste the code into the comments so ill add it to my original post.

Comment: When you execute the second ```df =```, you are deleting the previous one. Not sure about the exact final result you need, but either: 1. Do the csv reading, X, Y and scatter for the first set of data and then repeat the same for the second set of data; 2. you have the two datasets at the same time, but you'll have to call different names (such as ```df``` and ```df1``` or anything else suitable for you).

Comment: Thanks, i tried that but all i get is the same graph, cant seem to get both results to plot onto one graph.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242118/discussion-between-780-apm-and-fdireito).